# iOS: how to change the size of the UIScrollView content?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm now trying to create my own Text panel (with code highlighting and so on).

In fact everything is ready except one thing - scrolling

What I've done:
created `UIScrollView` and inserted my own view as a `subview` using Interface builder.

in `ViewController` `viewDidLoad` method I've pointed initial `textfield` size to be the `UIScrollView` content size.

And when user writes too much into my text field. I call delegate (which is `ViewController`) to change size.
To do that I simply write

```
[scrollView setContentSize:newSize];
```

And what I get is increasing of the scroll view but not my text field  - just blank lines appears. I think I need to set my view's size too but I can't figure out how...

And a second part of my question:
Every time I call `[textField setNeedsDisplay]` it calls `drawRect:` method with rectangle which is equal to the whole size of my view (which is much bigger than it's visible part). What will it look like if I try to use my view to modify file which size is more than 3 mb? How can I force it to redraw only visible part?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Part 1**:

The scroll view's content size is not actually related to the size or position of the views it contains. If you want to change the size of the content view as well as the scroll view's content, you need to call two different methods.

```
CGSize newSize;
UIScrollView *scrollView;
// assume self is the content view
CGRect newFrame = (CGRect){CGPointZero,newSize}; // Assuming you want to start at the top-left corner of the scroll view. Change CGPointZero as appropriate
[scrollView setContentSize:newSize]; // Change scroll view's content size
[self setFrame:newFrame]; // Change views actual size
```

**Part 2**:

`setNeedsDisplay` marks the entire view as needing display. To cause it to display only the visible part, you need to use `setNeedsDisplayInRect:visibleRect`.
Assuming the view is at the top-left corner (its frame's origin is 0) and the scroll view does not allow zooming, the visible rect can be found using the scroll view's content offset and bounds size.

```
CGRect visibleRect;
visibleRect.origin = [scrollView contentOffset];
visibleRect.size = [scrollView bounds].size;
[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:visibleRect];
```

You could also choose to draw a part of the visible rect if only part changes.

Comment: This almost works for me - I just need to change `CGPointZero`, as your code comment mentions.  However, I'm not sure what to put in place of that if I want my `UIScrollView` moved down ~300 pixels - any idea?

Comment: @Mike You just replace it with the coordinates you want to place it, or a point variable with those values. You would use something like `{{0,300},newSize}` to place your view 300 pixels below the top of the scroll view, and a negative value to place it above. Note that this moves the view within the scroll view, not starts the view already scrolled. If you want the latter, you need to change the scroll view's `contentOffset` property.

Comment: This is actually completely wrong.  If you do want to force the content size, you have to actually do it INSIDE laying out subviews.  (It doesn't matter, but setting needs display is pointless, as it does that anyway.)

Comment: Also the syntax is simply `.contentSize =`

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler than you think, for example you have an **UITextView** called "*textDesc*" inside your **UIScrollView**, and you want to know the size of content, so next step will looks like that:

```
int contentHeight = textDesc.frame.size.height + textDesc.frame.origin.y;
```

After calculating the size of *textDesc*, just set it:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, contentHeight))];
```

That's all, now your **scrollView** know the size of your text inside him, and will resize automatically, hope this helps, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Set your text field autoresizingMask property to flexible height and width:

```
[textField setAutoResizingMask:UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleWidth];
```

This should expand the view automatically when you change it's parent's size (the scrollView's contentSize)

Otherwise try:

```
[textField setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)];
```

just after you change the scroll view's contentsize.

Comment: The code should be: `[textField setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];` -- notice the lower-case-r in all instances of the word "resizing".

Answer (score -1):

### If you truly want to set (ie "override") the content size of a scroll view:

It's simply this,

```
someScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: blah, height: blah)
```

However, the whole point is - exactly like setting a frame - you have to do that in `layoutSubviews`.

It's completely pointless doing this, other than in `layoutSubviews`. (Just as it's pointless setting a frame other than in layout.)

### What the OP asked ..

In this QA the OP simply didn't understand how to set the height of the actual view in question (ie, the labels, etc).

Note that in general you NEVER, EVER set the literal property `.contentSize` of a scroll view.  (You would only do so in extremely unusual and advanced situations. It's likely a mistake that Apple even made it writable, there is no point in "normal" programming to change it or even see it.)