# How Do I Create A Simple Scroll View That Scrolls Through Static Images?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, interface-builder, scrollview

Perhaps it's something with Xcode 4.5+ or iOS 6 that makes my research fruitless so far, but...

- [Apple's own advice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html) hasn't worked for me. I set the contentSize to something different, and it causes no changes.
- I found this [wasn't unique to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101656/setting-the-content-size-of-my-uiscrollview-in-viewdidload-viewwillappear-has-no), but the answer in that question 1.) does not inform me about the problem and 2.) I'm left wondering if it's really impossible to create a simple, non-inheriting example of UIScrollView.  Thus, this question.
- A [better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464550/ios-how-to-change-the-size-of-the-uiscrollview-content)'s code was tried within viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear, but to no avail.

So what gives?  **Is it possible to create a simple, image-filled view that allows scrolling?** Say... something as easy as this [basic project I set up on github](https://github.com/hyliandanny/SimpleScrollViewExample) -- but working?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1e0hajdqxtuuebc/DHtfXwR4GJ

Comment: Thanks, @Zen, I've updated the github repo with your answer... but does that (and the answer given below) mean that there's no real way to do this in Interface Builder as implied in the Apple docs?

Comment: For that,I guess you'll have to set your views in `UIScrollView` object in nib with their origins at where they are supposed to be and get the maximum of width these views are going to have and for height, get the coordinate of the bottom left/right corner of the view at the bottom and set content size according to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create and initialize a `UIScrollView`
2. Add it as subview to the view of viewcontroller
3. Make an array of image names
4. In a loop create UIImageView and add the images and add imageviews into scrollview considering the width of images, set the frame of imageviews
5. Number of images is known and the width it consumes can be calulated from the loop itself use it to set the `contentSize` of the scrollview

Comment: I'm assuming this works because 1.) it sounds similar to what @Zen recommended in his comments, 2.) what Zen recommended worked for me in a stand-alone project (now up on github!) and 3.) it didn't work for what I needed it to, but it at least worked on that one case with some Interface Builder equivalence (put views within other views).